# How to use MongoDB aggregation for set operations (union, intersection, difference)

Tags: mongodb, set, aggregation

I have two collections:

- friends(id, name, etc)
- followers(id, name, etc)

How do i get the Intersection

[image: Intersection]

and the Union?

[image]

for id's that are the same in both sets?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/ ?

Answer (score 0):

[setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)

[setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)

[setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)

Are equivalent to

`Union` `Difference` and `Interaction`  set operations.